# Implement BackButton in React-Admin v4

Tags: react-admin

Before version 4, we could create BackButton like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import ArrowBack from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack';
import { goBack } from 'react-router-redux';


class BackButton extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.goBack();
    };

    render() {
        return <Button startIcon={<ArrowBack />} color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Назад</Button>;
    }
}

export default connect(null, {
    goBack,
})(BackButton);
```

How do we create BackButton in react-admin version 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

That library was deprecated a long time ago.
The natural upgrade of `react-router-redux` is `connected-react-router`.
In `react-admin` upgrade guide for version 4 is explained how to move away from `connected-react-router`:

Basically, now you have to use `useNavigate` hook from `react-router`:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html#removed-connected-react-router

Plus in your case you will have to change your component to a function component first.
Something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import ArrowBack from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';


const BackButton = props => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    handleClick = () => {
       navigate(-1);
    };

    return (
        <Button 
            startIcon={<ArrowBack />}
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            Назад
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Comment: That will be broken in case if you used direct link